# LUIS attach to slack

Tags: msdn, slack, azure-language-understanding

I am writing to you because I truly don't know what else I can do. When I try to select a channel after I checked "Fullfillment" the Action dropdown list remains empty, all there is to see is "Select Action ..."  --> no Channel and I don't know how to get them.

As I saw earlier "If you want to try the channels, click this button to add our Action Binding bot to your Slack team" I thought this had to do with me not having done that but after I created a Slack account and added the Action Binding bot Nothing changed !

I though that maybe I was supposed to register to some channels on Slack but I don't why that'd be the reason plus I can't find the public Channels.

So I am stuck there, please can you help me so I can use those channels ?

Comment: Are you sure you are using LUIS preview mode?

Comment: I just use LUIS.ai website,maybe it's not preview. where to find preview mode?  thank you

Comment: I've find the preview mode,But the Slack bot integration feature will be discontinued

Comment: Sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Log in to Slack and create a Slack Application for your bot https://api.slack.com/applications/new

2.Create application and set redirect URI

3.Create a Slack Bot

4.Add Interactive Messages (optional)

5.Configure Interactive Messages (optional)

6.Gather your Credentials https://slack.botframework.com/Content/StepAuth.png

7.Submit your Credentials

Answer (score 1):

LUIS no longer supported directly attach to slack now, but MS bot still support this function . Therefore, you need to register a bot, and then the right side of the page, click the channels slack ---- add button, it will show the detailed steps